# Ошибка в надстройке 3D на движке PenguinMod (LiveTest)

Tags: javascript

Я подготовил 3D-модель в файле .fbx и решил добавить её в проект с помощью расширения "3D". Но есть одна проблема — чтобы добавить модель, нужно сделать это по протоколу data uri, но некоторые символы не кодируются в base64, например проценты с двумя кружками и так далее. Как это решить?

Comment: `некоторые символы не кодируются в base64` - это невозможно по определению. наверно, вам стоит привести ваш код, который «не кодирует».

Comment: В PenguinMod не используется код. Там блоковая структура кода, которая позволяет заменить команды в блоки. В данном контексте я всё выразил правильно, не кодируется сама МОДЕЛЬ (её текст, если открыть в блокноте), а не код.

Comment: *"но некоторые символы не кодируются в base64, например проценты с двумя кружками и так далее"* - попробуйте не использовать эти символы. Ваш Кэп :-)